# How to Import Account as Partners & Contacts as Customer User through Dataloader or any other applications

Tags: data-loader

I need to import Accounts & Contacts to enable Community Users.

First I need to know how to Import Accounts & Contacts as Customer Users. I tried to put Ispartner Field as True, but couldn't find it in Dataloader.io.

Please guide me import Accounts & Conacts.

Answer (score 0):

DataLoader.io wont be any good,try the desktop app and use export all.
Below is the link to download http://www.cloudsuccess.com/resource-centre/apex-data-loader-archive/

Comment: But what is the difference between Data Loader and Apex Data Loader??

Comment: well in dataloader.io we cannot get certain fields(unless you do soql query) where as when you use the desktop app you can user "Export All" to export all fields that are associated with a certain object .

Comment: Customer Portal Account field on Account - Is Read Only. I tried to Import bulk Accounts to enable them as community users but but "IsCustomerPortal" field is ReadOnly. Steps carried : Created an Account, created contacts below that account, then tried update earlier created accounts. But was unable to update "IsCustomerPortal" as that field was readonly for all the profiles in  my org. I had an error like "Cannot explicitly enable account as Customer Portal"